# Avoid class pollution while including module

Tags: ruby

Is there a concise way to limit method visibility within the module while including it? In other words, I'd like to limit polluting the class with helper methods only used in the included module.

```
module Bar
  def call
    hide_me
  end

  private

  # make this method only callable within this module
  def hide_me
    'visible'
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def unrelated_method
    hide_me
  end
end

# that's ok
Foo.new.call #=> 'visible'

# that's not
Foo.new.unrelated_method #=> 'visible'
```

I'm ok with calling it via `Bar.instance_method(:hide_me).bind(self).call`, I just don't want to worry about accessing or redefining a helper method from some module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap a class into the module and use private methods within the class, like so:

```
module Bar

  def call
    BarClass.new.call
  end

  class BarClass
    def call
      hide_me
    end

    private 

    def hide_me
      puts "invisible"
    end

  end

end

class Foo

  include Bar

  def call_bar
    call
  end

  def this_method_fails
    hide_me
  end

end
```

Comment: I suppose it now pollutes with that class instead. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Nakilon correct. This strategy *limits* (but does not eliminate) pollution by reducing the polluted namespace to a single class. Ultimately, including a Module forms a parent-child relationship, and in ruby, children can access the private methods of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

One can do what you want by including the module to the class and then undefining the unwanted included methods.

First construct a module.

```
module M
  def cat
    puts "meow"
  end
  def dog
    puts "woof"
  end
  def owl
    puts "who?"
  end

  private

  def frog
    puts "ribbit"
  end
  def pig
    puts "oink"
  end
end
```

Confirm the methods now exist.

```
M.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:cat, :dog, :owl]
M.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:frog, :pig]
```

Create the class, including the module `M`.

```
class C
  def froggie
    frog
  end
  def cat
    puts "meow-meow"
  end
  include M
end
```

Check the instance methods.

```
C.instance_methods & [:cat, :dog, :owl, :froggie]
  #=> [:cat, :froggie, :dog, :owl]
C.private_instance_methods & [:frog, :pig]
  #=> [:frog, :pig]
```

and confirm `:cat` is owned by `C` and not by `M`.

```
C.instance_method(:cat).owner
  #=> C
```

Now use the method [Module#undef_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) to undefine the unwanted methods from the module.

```
class C
  [:cat, :owl, :pig].each { |m|
    undef_method(m) unless instance_method(m).owner == self }
end
```

The `unless...` clause is needed so that the instance method `:cat` defined in `C` is not undefined.

Confirm the methods were undefined.

```
C.instance_methods & [[:cat, :dog, :owl, :froggie]
  #=> [:cat, :froggie, :dog]
C.private_instance_methods & [:frog, :pig]
  #=> [:frog]
```

Execute the methods.

```
c = C.new
c.cat
  #=> "meow-meow"
c.dog
  #=> "woof"
c.froggie
  #=> "ribbit"
```

Comment: It works, but requires you to know exactly what methods to undefine and requires additional code on the class side. A little bit too messy

Comment: You obviously need to know which of the module's instance methods are to be used or which are not to be used and one can easily compute one from the other: `used_public_instance_methods + <unused_public_instance_methods = M.public_instance_methods` (similar for private instance methods).

Comment: I suppose you could define an `included` method that would automatically undefine the method you don't want to be included. Right?

Comment: @Nakilon, yes, but after re-reading the question I'm not sure what is being asked.